# How do I tell apt and all the other tools to show suggests?

Tags: apt, configuration

If I run `apt-get` I get suggestion but if I run `apt` or `aptitude` I do not get suggestion. What I should put in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` so suggestion are shown in `aptitude` and `apt`.